# Changing the arrow-keys focus to moving the player instead of buttons

Tags: c#, forms, button, arrow-keys

So I am building a game using a form (similar to the snake game) in c# and I want navigate the player with the arrow-keys. Near the grid(board) where the game is played I have a few buttons such as; pause, start etc. When i click the arrows keys the focus is on the buttons(it is browsing the buttons) instead of moving the player. How could i change this?

regards,

Henk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must set your form `KeyPreview` to true and subscribe to the Form's `KeyDown`event , in the designer or adding this line to your form's constructor:

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
```

Then, add this code for the keydown event. Basically, it tells the event that the key press has already be handled if the key pressed is one of the arrows:

```
private void Form3_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left ||e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MovePlayer(e.KeyCode);
    }
}

private void MovePlayer(Keys key)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case Keys.Up:
            // your player moveup code
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```